# Нужно найти R паралельних резисторов 1/R=(1/R1)+(1/R2)+(1/R3) . Как перевернуть дробь?

Tags: c++, математика, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <TCHAR.H>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    double R1, R2, R3;
    cout << "Введите номиналы(кОм)" << endl;
    cout << "R1 ->";
    cin >> R1;
    cout << "R2 ->";
    cin >> R2;
    cout << "R3 ->";
    cin >> R3;
    cout << setw(40) << "Вариант расчета" << endl;
    cout << "0-последовательное 1-параллельное 2-параллельно – последовательное";
    int variant;
    cout << "Выберите вариант ->";
    cin >> variant;
    long double Rrez1 = R1 + R2 + R3;
    long double Rrez2 = (1 / R1) + (1 / R2) + (1 / R3);
    long double Rrez3 = R1 + ((R2 * R3) / (R2 + R3));
    if (variant == 0)
    {
        cout << "R=" << Rrez1 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (variant == 1)

        cout << "R=" << Rrez2 << endl;
    }
    
    {if (variant == 2)
        cout << "R =" << Rrez3 << endl;
    }
   
     system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну если вы нашли 1/R = число, то согласно пропорции R = cколько? R = 1/число.

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это тоже, что и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так что

```
long double Rrez2 = 1 / (1 / R1 + 1 / R2 + 1 / R3);
```

Comment: ну или если тут только три резистора, то `r = (r1*r2*r3)/(r1*r2+r1*r3+r2*r3)`. Да, тут действий больше, но иногда так удобнее.

Comment: @KoVadim Наверное, для аналитических вычислений? Но не для численных компьютерных.

Comment: Если нужны именно точные вычисления ( ну мало чего ), то эта формула лучше - в ней одно деление